# Changing Azure Database 'encryption enabled' fixes the issue , weird

Tags: .net, sql-server, azure, asp.net-web-api, paas

I am into a weird situation that I am facing

I have a SQL database hosted on Azure, PaaS.

Now, the data is queried through a stored procedure with one or multiple search parameters, like `EmployeeNo`, `Email` etc,

The stored procedure is working fine, as tested, with both parameters. And, is working fine in production as well.

**But**, what happens is that all of a sudden, in the middle of a day or night, it fetches data through `EmployeeNo`, but refuses to fetch through `Email`, throwing an erro:

> 500 Internal Server Error

Interestingly, what works for me is:

[image: My DB Temp Solution]

Changing the *`Encryption Enabled`* to *`true`* and *vice versa*

Why is it happening so..?

Can anybody help..

**Edit:** The database and the calling API are both hosted on Azure. And, when the concerned procedure is run via SSMS it runs perfect, as said before.
The problem seems recurrent.

**Edit -2 :** As per the comments the error I see in the logs is

> Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

*But*, I do have increased the `CommandTimeout` to `90` in my code, just in case

Full exception is like :

> Exception Message: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>   Inner Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
>   Stack Trace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
>      at VL.SJ.EMDM.Data.DataProvider.EmployeDataProvider.GetEmployeeDetails(SearchEmployee searchEmployee)
>      at VL.SJ.EMDM.Web.API.Controllers.EmployeeController.GetEmployeeDetails(SearchEmployee searchEmployee)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetExecutor>b__c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
>      at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c__DisplayClass5.<ExecuteAsync>b__4()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: `500 Internal Server Error` is a web application error, *not* a database error. What does the API's log show? If errors aren't logged, you should add proper logging and monitoring (using App Insights perhaps?) and see what the actual error is.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The only error I see in the log is ; `Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.` Please check my edit

Comment: Sounds like a legitimate timeout - are you sure your query isn't doing something that occasionally causes a lot of load? Are there any workloads on the DB that could be putting it under significant load that your query takes a while to execute (long blocking chains etc). I'd be surprised if changing the encryption settings would fix a long wait (but you can't rule out anything in IT), are you sure it's not coincidence?

Comment: That's not `only`. Either the database froze or the application tried to execute something that took so long that the query timed out. Changing the encryption setting is a *major* operation - it decrypts or encrypts the entire database. By the time that's finished, any transient problems have gone away, and any long-running operations have finished if they haven't been aborted

Comment: What does the *entire* logged exception look like? Or do you only log the message? The exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()` contains any inner exceptions and their call stack. This can point to the method in your code that started the long-running query.

Comment: I did add the exception as well, but the fact that why it works and then finally stops uncertainly..

Comment: Plus the problem is @PanagiotisKanavos  .. it _keeps on working while we fetch data through one parameter, say , EmployeeNo, and throws exception when done same with `Email`_, I wonder why‬ –?
As the same, `Email`, starts to work when I change the Encryption, before the problem arises again

Comment: @Irf if `Email` isn't indexed, that query will scan the entire table. The call stack points to `VL.SJ.EMDM.Data.DataProvider.EmployeDataProvider.GetEmployeeDetails`. What does that method do? What does the code look like? Have you tried searching for records by email from SSMS or Azure Data Studio? How fast/slow is the query? What does the execution plan look like?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you seem to have pointed to the right direction, I have indexed it now, and hopefully this should be the root cause, Thanx.. Will check/ monitor how it goes.

Comment: Please add it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Hi Sir, can you add it as an answer.. so that I shall accept it.?